# Unity Hololens WorldAnchorTransferBatch ExportAsync fails most of the time

Tags: networking, serialization, unity-game-engine, sharing, hololens

I'm trying to create a hologram that is shared among multiple Hololenses by following Microsoft's Holograms 240 tutorial at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/holographic/holograms_240

The network connection is working fine, and I have all the correct permissions in my project settings. The issue is that aside from a rare occurence, the call to WorldAnchorTransferBatch.ExportAsync() will fail with a SerializationCompletionReason.UnknownError and print out "Failed to world lock serialization failed"

I haven't been able to find any information about this error in my searching. Does anyone know what the cause of this could be?

Comment: Are you running on the emulator or on a HoloLens?

Comment: I'm running on a HoloLens

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem with the latest Unity release 5.5.0b11 but only the actual hardware, always works in the emulator.  Are you using that version also?

Comment: I'm using Unity 5.4.0f3-HTP Edu